# Python OpenCV cv2.waitKey(1) cause video window to freeze/not responding

Tags: python, opencv, freeze, opencv3.0

So I'm running this piece of code.

```
import cv2
frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Resources/test_video.mp4")
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if img is None:
        break
    img = cv2.resize(img, (frameWidth, frameHeight))
    cv2.imshow("Result", img)
    keyPressed = cv2.waitKey(5)
    if keyPressed == ord('q'):
        break;
```

test_video.mp4 is a short [video here](https://streamable.com/0gmmtr) The moment it finishes running, the "Result" window freezes and become not responding. Even when I press "Q", nothing happens.

I run the program on Anaconda Spyder. `cv2` is installed using pip install `opencv-python`

Edit: the code has been fixed so that the window exit when "q" is pressed

Comment: you may use sys.exit() before the break.(You should import sys)

Comment: Isn't exiting the entire program a bit overkill ?

Comment: Yes but you are going to kill your program after a break eventually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these two lines at the end:

```
import cv2
frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Resources/test_video.mp4")
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        if img is None:
            break
        #img = cv2.resize(img, (frameWidth, frameHeight))
        cv2.imshow("Result", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
             break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It could be that it's failing to release the resource at the end of the script. See this post for further reference: [What's the meaning of cv2.videoCapture.release()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213499/whats-the-meaning-of-cv2-videocapture-release)

It also seems to be a common issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104304/opencv-python-crashes-after-playing-a-video) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868348/window-freezing-even-after-using-waitkey-and-destroyallwindows-in-opencv).

Edit: Update to respond to comment requesting video exit on 'q'. Replace the lines:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

With:

```
key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == ord('q'):
    break
```

Tested and behaviour is as expected using:

- Python 3.7
- OpenCV 3.4.2

Comment: This makes the program stop freezing, but I have another problem. When I press "Q", nothing happen while it should have break. Could you explain why ?

Comment: Have updated the answer with some code to allow video to exit on 'q' press.